# IF statement not correctly identifying if an object contains a string within an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

This is probably a really simple question but when attempting to check if a string contains another string contained in an array it doesn't have the behaviour I expect.

I have a script that returns all folders within C:\Users older than x amount of time.

I don't want this script to run on `C:\Users\Public` or `C:\Users\defaultuser0` so I've created an array with `"\Public\", "\defaultuser0\"` then check if the current object contains these strings. If it does match I don't want to do anything with the values.

```
#Enter in the path to search for.
#Using the 'Recurse' switch will search through all sub-directories as well.
$Path = "C:\Users\"
$RequiredAccounts = @("Public","defaultuser0")

#Searching for directories that haven't been updated in 12 Months.
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-12) )} | select FullName, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv C:\Oldfiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

```
#Read the CSV file into an array of objects
Get-Content "C:\Oldfiles.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -ne '"FullName","LastWriteTime"') { # Do not run on table headers
        # Test output
        Write-Output($_)
        Write-Output($RequiredAccounts[0])

        # If the value in $_ contains any value in the $RequiredAccounts array
        if($_.ToString() -like $RequiredAccounts) {
            Write-Output("SUCCESS")
        } else {
            Write-Output("These strings do not match")
        }
    }
}
```

When running this it returns

```
"C:\Users\Public\Videos","**/**/20** **:**:**"
Public
These strings do not match
```

For all folders that it finds that match the criteria/

However changing it to:

```
# If the value in $_ contains any value in the $RequiredAccounts array
if($_.ToString() -notlike $RequiredAccounts) {
   Write-Output("SUCCESS")
} else {
   Write-Output("These strings do not match")
}
```

Returns

```
"C:\Users\Public\Videos","**/**/20** **:**:**"
Public
SUCCESS
```

I've also tried

```
if($_.ToString() -contains $RequiredAccounts)
if($_.ToString() -match $RequiredAccounts)
if($_ -like $RequiredAccounts)
```

Comment: What format is ToString() using ?  Maybe use ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: @jdweng honestly I'm not sure what you mean, attempting to enter anything into the ToString() overload throws an error that it doesn't accept `Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1"`

Comment: Lets fix one issue at a time,  Instead of using Get-Content use Import-CSV which will simplify code.

Comment: @jdweng updated to Import-CSV, same output as previously

Comment: A couple of observations - ```”c:\users\public\aaa.txt” -like “public”``` returns ```false``` - you want ```… -like “*public*”``` instead, and ```… -like @(“public”, “defaultuser0”)``` is equivalent to ```… -like “public defaultuser0”``` because the array gets “stringified” into a single value before the ```-like``` operator is evaluated - that is, it *doesn’t* do a ```-like``` against each array item separately, but combines them and then compares to the combined value…

Comment: @mclayton Thank you! Fixed both those issues and the output is what I expected! Saved me a lot of head scratching. You should write it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to Get Any working.  Try following :

```
$Path = "C:\Users\"
$table = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$table | Format-Table
$RequiredAccounts = @("Public","defaultuser0")
$filteredTable = $table | Where-Object { $name = $_.Name; [Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$RequiredAccounts,[Func[object,bool]] {param($x) $name.Contains($x) })}
$filteredTable | Format-Table
```